# Stick Plot for wind speed and direction data in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series, plotly

I'd like to plot a stick plot for wind speed/ direction data similar to this:

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Stick-plot-of-mean-daily-wind-speed-and-direction-measured-at-Valentia-Island-from_fig5_226577448

[image]

I've found a good plot in the excelent oce package, but I'd like to make this same kind of plot using ggplot (or plotley).

```
WindSpeed<-c(1,2,3,5,7,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
WindDir<-c(180,90,320,200,350,10,270,50,9,100,110,129)
TimeStamp<-c("2018-01-02 01:00","2018-01-02 02:00","2018-01-02 03:00","2018-01-02 04:00","2018-01-02 05:00","2018-01-02 06:00","2018-01-02 07:00","2018-01-02 08:00","2018-01-02 09:00","2018-01-02 10:00","2018-01-02 11:00","2018-01-02 12:00")

DF<-data.frame(TimeStamp,WindSpeed, WindDir)
```

The above Wind direction data is in compass direction units (the compass direction the wind is blowing from), so I'd like the 180 data to point straight up, and the 270 data point to point straight to the right (AKA coming from the west and blowing East).

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a free-code-service (http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). I suggest a combination of [`segments`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/segments.html) and some trig functions would work well enough. (You'll also need `as.POSIXct` to convert your timestamp, though you'll need to add `:00` to each.)

Comment: actually they'll covert just fine without the extra `:00`

Comment: I agree with the comment that your question will be more warmly received if you "show your work." This helps the community work better, helps you to learn, and helps you get well-directed responses. Also, you have typos in your last three timestamps. Fixing those will help make your question reproducible.

Comment: This is a more challenging question than I anticipated, partly because you have to get the x / y ratio right for the angles to be correct, and in this case one will be a date-time and one will be normal numeric. I think this can be addressed by using `geom_segment(aes(x = hour, y = 0,  xend = TimeStamp + lubridate::dhours(WindSpeed * 1 * -cos(WindDir / 360 * 2 * pi)), yend = WindSpeed * 1 * -sin(WindDir / 360 * 2 * pi)))` in combination with `coord_fixed(ratio = 60 * 60)`.

Comment: Crap, just saw this, thanks @hrbrmstr, no idea what I was thinking wrt `":00"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jon Spring's code works. I'll verify (with slightly different data) and show the output with his code.

Slightly different data, with different `WindDir` to highlight the diagonals (and 30s):

```
WindSpeed<-c(1,2,3,5,7,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
WindDir <- c(0, 30, 45, 60, 90, 120, 135, 150, 180, 225, 270, 315)
TimeStamp<-c("2018-01-02 01:00","2018-01-02 02:00","2018-01-02 03:00","2018-01-02 04:00","2018-01-02 05:00","2018-01-02 06:00","2018-01-02 07:00","2018-01-02 08:00","2018-01-02 09:00","2018-01-02 10:00","2018-01-02 11:00","2018-01-02 12:00")
DF<-data.frame(TimeStamp,WindSpeed, WindDir)
DF$TimeStamp <- as.POSIXct(DF$TimeStamp)
```

For a little added clarity, I augmented Jon's code for arrow ends, starting points, and color (grouped naïvely).

```
ggplot(DF) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = TimeStamp,
                   y = 0,
                   xend = TimeStamp + lubridate::dhours(WindSpeed * 1 * -cos((90-WindDir) / 360 * 2 * pi)),
                   yend = WindSpeed * 1 * -sin((90-WindDir) / 360 * 2 * pi),
                   col = factor(TimeStamp)
                   ),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")) ) +
  geom_point(aes(TimeStamp, 0), size = 1) +
  coord_fixed(3600) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: sample wind-dir plot with modified wind direction]

I think this clearly shows the 45s as good, specifically the last one hitting the grid lines.

Using your data and this code:

```
WindSpeed<-c(1,2,3,5,7,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
WindDir<-c(180,90,320,200,350,10,270,50,9,100,110,129)
TimeStamp<-c("2018-01-02 01:00","2018-01-02 02:00","2018-01-02 03:00","2018-01-02 04:00","2018-01-02 05:00","2018-01-02 06:00","2018-01-02 07:00","2018-01-02 08:00","2018-01-02 09:00","2018-01-02 10:00","2018-01-02 11:00","2018-01-02 12:00")
DF<-data.frame(TimeStamp,WindSpeed, WindDir)
DF$TimeStamp <- as.POSIXct(DF$TimeStamp)
```

presents:

[image: sample windplot with original data]

Comment: FWIW: The trigonometry is a bit overdoing here, and might also not follow usual conventions. (using angle `90-Dir` means that 0 degree are pointing upwards and 90 degrees to the right.). An easier formula is `xend = x + speed * cos(direction[angle] * pi / 180)` and `yend = y + speed * sin(direction[angle] * pi / 180)`. (with 0 pointing to the right as per most common convention.)

Comment: "Common convention" is a clear contradiction between "geometry" and "everything navigation". If (say) one is navigating in a boat or airplane heading due north, the heading is `000`, and `090` is due east. This applies to wind, too. So while I could simplify `sin` and `90-Dir`, I thought it better to be declarative that I was doing the geometry-vs-navigation conversion internally. So since the question is about wind, 0 pointing to the right is wrong. @tjebo

Comment: that is interesting and a valid point. also not quite the point I wanted to make, although my wording might not have been very clear. Just wanted to add this because I think the "/ 360 * 2 * pi" was odd and not all people might want to use this type of plot for wind or navigation

Comment: @tjebo not everybody wanting to use it for wind or nav is certainly possible, would you have me answer a different question then posed in the OP? It is specifically about *"wind speed/ direction data"* (OP's wording), so to _not_ account for that would produce the wrong results. As for `/ 360 * 2 * pi`, when debugging **somebody else's code** (or your code from 4.5 years ago, as this is for me), does it makes more sense to you to see that code or instead `* 0.01745329`? Yes, it's verbose, but it's clearer in what the magic constants stand for. ("Self-documenting" in a way.)