# Stickplot vectors not accurately visualizing direction

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display wind and water movement data in [stacked plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJhUY.png) but am currently running into an issue with displaying direction. The water movement is significantly smaller and this seems to be biasing the vector `xend` calculation, resulting in vectors that visually appear only north and south orientation. A similar issue occurred for other data after lengthening the time period of the plot, so there must be something that I am failing to grasp within the vector calculation. Simple multiplication of the `lubridate` within `xend` gets the vectors closer to realistic orientation but I am unsure of why. How might this be manipulated to accurately represent different magnitudes and time periods?

Also looked at question [Stick Plot for wind speed and direction data in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895843/stick-plot-for-wind-speed-and-direction-data-in-ggplot)

Example of different speeds with smaller speeds washing out the vector direction:

```
library(ggplot2)
WindSpeed<-c(0.05,0.02,0.03,0.07,0.09,0.01,0.006,0.05,0.04,0.08,0.03,0.04)
WindSpeed<-c(0.5,0.2,0.3,0.7,0.9,0.1,0.06,0.5,0.4,0.8,0.3,0.4)
WindSpeed<-c(5,2,3,7,9,1,6,5,4,8,3,4)
WindDir <- c(0, 30, 45, 60, 90, 120, 135, 150, 180, 225, 270, 315)
TimeStamp<-c("2018-01-02 01:00","2018-01-02 02:00","2018-01-02 03:00","2018-01-02 04:00","2018-01-02 05:00","2018-01-02 06:00","2018-01-02 07:00","2018-01-02 08:00","2018-01-02 09:00","2018-01-02 10:00","2018-01-02 11:00","2018-01-02 12:00")
DF<-data.frame(TimeStamp, WindSpeed, WindDir)
DF$TimeStamp <- as.POSIXct(DF$TimeStamp)

ggplot(DF) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = TimeStamp,
                   y = 0,
                   xend = TimeStamp + lubridate::dhours(WindSpeed * 1 * -cos((90-WindDir) / 360 * 2 * pi)),
                   yend = WindSpeed * 1 * -sin((90-WindDir) / 360 * 2 * pi),
                   col = factor(TimeStamp)
  ),
  arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")) ) +
  geom_point(aes(TimeStamp, 0), size = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong in your code, it's just the way that you're calculating your data. As `xend` and `yend` are dependent of `WindSpeed`, if `WindSpeed` is too small, you can barely perceive the change but it is plotted accordingly. Here I add a table calculating `xend` and `yend` as in your plot for large or small values of `Windspeed`, notice the factor change between each column:

```r
DF %>% mutate(XEND = TimeStamp + lubridate::dhours(WindSpeed * 1 * -cos((90-WindDir) / 360 * 2 * pi)),
              YEND = WindSpeed * 1 * -sin((90-WindDir) / 360 * 2 * pi)) %>%
  mutate(LargeWind = c(5,2,3,7,9,1,6,5,4,8,3,4)) %>%
  mutate(largeXEND = TimeStamp + lubridate::dhours(LargeWind * 1 * -cos((90-WindDir) / 360 * 2 * pi)),
         largeYEND = LargeWind * 1 * -sin((90-WindDir) / 360 * 2 * pi))

             TimeStamp WindSpeed WindDir                XEND          YEND LargeWind           largeXEND     largeYEND
1  2018-01-02 01:00:00     0.050       0 2018-01-02 01:00:00 -5.000000e-02         5 2018-01-02 01:00:00 -5.000000e+00
2  2018-01-02 02:00:00     0.020      30 2018-01-02 01:59:24 -1.732051e-02         2 2018-01-02 01:00:00 -1.732051e+00
3  2018-01-02 03:00:00     0.030      45 2018-01-02 02:58:43 -2.121320e-02         3 2018-01-02 00:52:43 -2.121320e+00
4  2018-01-02 04:00:00     0.070      60 2018-01-02 03:56:21 -3.500000e-02         7 2018-01-01 21:56:16 -3.500000e+00
5  2018-01-02 05:00:00     0.090      90 2018-01-02 04:54:36  0.000000e+00         9 2018-01-01 20:00:00  0.000000e+00
6  2018-01-02 06:00:00     0.010     120 2018-01-02 05:59:28  5.000000e-03         1 2018-01-02 05:08:02  5.000000e-01
7  2018-01-02 07:00:00     0.006     135 2018-01-02 06:59:44  4.242641e-03         6 2018-01-02 02:45:26  4.242641e+00
8  2018-01-02 08:00:00     0.050     150 2018-01-02 07:58:30  4.330127e-02         5 2018-01-02 05:30:00  4.330127e+00
9  2018-01-02 09:00:00     0.040     180 2018-01-02 09:00:00  4.000000e-02         4 2018-01-02 09:00:00  4.000000e+00
10 2018-01-02 10:00:00     0.080     225 2018-01-02 10:03:23  5.656854e-02         8 2018-01-02 15:39:24  5.656854e+00
11 2018-01-02 11:00:00     0.030     270 2018-01-02 11:01:48  3.673940e-18         3 2018-01-02 14:00:00  3.673940e-16
12 2018-01-02 12:00:00     0.040     315 2018-01-02 12:01:41 -2.828427e-02         4 2018-01-02 14:49:42 -2.828427e+00
```

Does it make sense ? Or did I misunderstand your question ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am aware that the vectors are technically the correct values, but I am searching for a way to either apply some sort of scaling or change the ```xend``` calculation in order to better depict the inverse relationship that should appear in the linked image of the question.