# Stick plot wind size change

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot wind speed and direction on a stick plot. Following the answers in this question [Stick Plot for wind speed and direction data in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895843/stick-plot-for-wind-speed-and-direction-data-in-ggplot) I managed to make the plot, but the size is too small, unreadable and I can not change it.

The code that I used is this:

```
DF <- read.table("C:\\...\\DF.CSV", header=T, sep=",", dec=".", as.is=T)
DF$Date <- as.POSIXct(DF$Date)


ggplot(DF) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Date,
                   y = 0,
                   xend = Date + lubridate::dhours(WindSpeed * 1 * -cos((270-WindDir) / 360 * 2 * pi)),
                   yend = WindSpeed * 1 * -sin((270-WindDir) / 360 * 2 * pi),
                   colour = "segment"
  )) +
  geom_point(aes(Date, 0), size = 0.01) +
  coord_fixed(3600) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(y="Wind", x="Date") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 day") + 
  geom_point(aes(Date, Sampling), size = 2)
```

And the result is this:

[image]

Comment: Remove the line `coord_fixed(40000) +`

Comment: If I remove `coord-fixed` the direction of the wind becomes wrong (40000 was a mistake, it has to be 3600)

Comment: then try changing to `coord_fixed(10800)` and change the `xend` to `Windspeed * 3` instead of `Windspeed * 1`. This should stretch your plot vertically but give you a compensatory stretch of the x component of your arrows to preserve direction. I can't test this because you didn't provide sample data, but it should work.