# Velocity plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I would like to create a velocity time-series plot similar to what was previously asked in this thread: [Stick Plot for wind speed and direction data in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895843/stick-plot-for-wind-speed-and-direction-data-in-ggplot)

I tried doing the plot using my data but there is an error saying

> "Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date
> only."

Can anyone help me figure this out? I am quite new to R programming so it would really help me a lot. Here is my script:

```
Speed <-c(24,23,23,24,26,27,27,27,26,24)
Dir <- c(108,105,103,100,97,96,97,99,101,103)
Date <-c(2016-08-01,2016-08-02,2016-08-3,2016-08-4,2016-08-5,2016-08-6,2016-09-7,2016-09-8,2016-09-9,2016-09-10)

DF <-data.frame(Speed,Dir,Date)
DF$Date <- as.Date(1,as.Date(DF$Date,origin = "2016-08-04"))

ggplot(DF) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Date,
                   y = 0,
                   xend = Date + lubridate::dhours(Speed * 1 * -cos((90-Dir) / 360 * 2 * pi)),
                   yend = Speed * 1 * -sin((90-Dir) / 360 * 2 * pi),
                   col = factor(Date)
  ),
  arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")) ) +
  geom_point(aes(Date, 0), size = 1) +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format('%b'), breaks = date_breaks('1 month'))+
  coord_fixed(3600) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date("016-08-04", "%Y-%m-%d"), 
                xmax = as.Date("2016-09-18",  "%Y-%m-%d"),ymin = -Inf,ymax = Inf))
```

Comment: Is that really how your date vales are? Because `x <-2016-08-01` just returns 2007. That's just subtraction of numbers. Did you mean to put those in quotes? Like `Date <- c("2016-08-01", "2016-08-02", ...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @MrFlick says, you first need to put quotes around your dates. But the error you posted about happens because of your line

```
xend = Date + lubridate::dhours(Speed * 1 * -cos((90-Dir) / 360 * 2 * pi))
```

This uses the `dhours()` function from the `lubridate` package to add an increment of hours to the dates. However, this has the side effect of converting the dates from R's built in `Date` type to lubridate's `Date` type. `ggplot`'s `geom_segment()` will only work with dates of R's built in type. You can just get rid of the call to the `dhours()` function.

I've also cleaned up a few other things in the code that makes the plot, in particular setting a fixed coordinate ratio via `coord_fixed(1)` so that the angles you want are faithfully represented. You might notice that these arrows seem to be pointing *away* from the directions specified by `Dir`. To make the arrows point toward `Dir`, you would remove the negative signs before `sin` and `cos`.

```
#establish the data
Speed <-c( 24, 23, 23, 24, 26, 27, 27, 27, 26, 24 )
Dir <- c( 108, 105, 103, 100, 97, 96, 97, 99, 101, 103 )
Date <- c('2016-08-01', '2016-08-02', '2016-08-3', '2016-08-4', '2016-08-5', '2016-08-6', '2016-09-7', '2016-09-8', '2016-09-9', '2016-09-10')

DF <- data.frame( Speed, Dir, Date )
DF$Date <- as.Date(1, as.Date(DF$Date, origin = "2016-08-04"))

# make the plot
ggplot(DF) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = Date,
                     y = 0,
                     xend = Date + Speed * 1 * cos( (90-Dir) / 360 * 2 * pi),
                     yend = Speed * 1 * sin( (90-Dir) / 360 * 2 * pi),
                     col = factor(Date)
    ),
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")) ) +
    geom_point(aes(Date, 0), size = 1) +
    scale_x_date(labels = date_format('%b'), breaks = date_breaks('1 month')) +
    coord_fixed(1) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: Plot with colored arrows pointing in the direction given by Dir, with length given by Speed.]