# Adding legend for velocity plot - key glyph length to represent value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently asked a question about how to do a [velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69355320/velocity-plot-in-ggplot) plot in ggplot.

Now, I would like to ask for your help in creating a legend that would correspond to speed in my data. I am aiming for something like this [arrow legend](https://tos.org/oceanography/assets/images/content/34-1-susanto-f2.jpg) where its length would correspond to 5 m/s or 0.5 m/s of the current plot.

Thank you and I hope you can help me.

Here is my script:

```
Speed <- c(24, 23, 23, 24, 26, 27, 27, 27, 26, 24)
Dir <- c(108, 105, 103, 100, 97, 96, 97, 99, 101, 103)
Date <- c('2016-08-01', '2016-08-02', '2016-08-3', '2016-08-4', '2016-08-5', '2016-08-6', '2016-09-7', '2016-09-8', '2016-09-9', '2016-09-10')

DF <- data.frame( Speed, Dir, Date )
DF$Date <- as.Date(1, as.Date(DF$Date, origin = "2016-08-04"))

# make the plot
ggplot(DF) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = Date,
                     y = 0,
                     xend = Date + Speed * 1 * cos( (90-Dir) / 360 * 2 * pi),
                     yend = Speed * 1 * sin( (90-Dir) / 360 * 2 * pi),
                     col = factor(Date)
    ),
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")) ) +
    geom_point(aes(Date, 0), size = 1) +
    scale_x_date(labels = date_format('%b'), breaks = date_breaks('1 month')) +
    coord_fixed(1) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest would be by annotation outside the plot area. If the length should be corresponding to the actual length of arrows in the plot, I think it would make sense to have either vertical or horizontal arrows.

You can precalculate them in a separate data frame and use this for annotation. Here how I would make horizontal arrows for a horizontal arrow legend. Note, the Speed of 0.5m/s is super small, and it has indeed an arrow head, but it is tiny!

Other comments in the code

> NB I have slightly modified the trigonometric functions. Calculating the angle with 90-Dir means that 0 degree is pointing upwards and 90 degree to the right, which might not always be convention.

```r
library(tidyverse)

Speed <- c(24, 23, 23, 24, 26, 27, 27, 27, 26, 24)
Dir <- c(108, 105, 103, 100, 97, 96, 97, 99, 101, 103)
Date <- c("2016-08-01", "2016-08-02", "2016-08-3", "2016-08-4", "2016-08-5", "2016-08-6", "2016-09-7", "2016-09-8", "2016-09-9", "2016-09-10")

DF <- data.frame(Speed, Dir, Date)
DF$Date <- as.Date(1, as.Date(DF$Date, origin = "2016-08-04"))

## I pre-calculate those, because I prefer to have the data frames ready and
## my plots slightly cleaner
DF <-
  DF %>%
  mutate(
    xend = Date + Speed * 1 * cos((90 - Dir) * pi / 180),
    yend = 0 + Speed * 1 * sin((90 - Dir) * pi / 180)
  )

## The joy starts here - defining x or y coordinates for your annotation can
## be daunting.
df_leg <-
  data.frame(
    Speed = c(0.5, 5),
    y = 2*min(DF$yend),
    Dir = 90, Date = range(DF$Date)
  ) %>%
  ## for the label x coord
  mutate(xend = Date + Speed * 1 * cos((90-Dir) * pi / 180))

## your plot, just slightly modified
ggplot(DF) +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x = Date, y = 0,
    xend = xend, yend = yend, col = factor(Date)
  ),
  arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm"))
  ) +
  geom_point(aes(Date, 0), size = 1) +
  geom_segment(
    data = df_leg,
    aes(
      x = Date, y = y, xend = xend,
      yend = y
    ), 
    ## you need to experiment with the arrow length, I'd pass a vector
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(3:4, "pt")), show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = df_leg, aes(x = xend, y = y, label = paste(Speed, "m/s")),
    hjust = -.1
  ) +
  scale_x_date(labels = scales::date_format("%b"), breaks = scales::date_breaks("1 month")) +
  coord_fixed(1, ylim = c(min(DF$yend), 0), clip = "off") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: this is amazing! thank you. However, I have a few more questions.

1. I would like it if there is only one arrow legend. I only want the 5m/s.
2. Can I change it to a line instead of an arrow? I want to remove the arrowheads.
3. How can I change the location of the legend inside the plot? 

I am extremely sorry for the questions. I am a beginner at coding and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @okscientist 1) you can see I created a data frame for the arrows. just make one row. 2) remove the arrow part from the respective geom_segment call 3) as commented in my answer, you can play around ad libitum with x and y coordinates of your arrow.

Comment: hi! 1) I edited the df_leg to Speed = 5. However, the result is two arrows with speed of 5 2) I removed the arrow = arrow in geom_segment call. It seemed to work but there is an error 3) I do not understand this i'm sorry

Comment: @okscientist run my code in a completely empty session, and then try around. You don't need to be scared, you cannot break anything. I am sure that by following my suggestions, and trying a little bit more, maybe give it  2-3 days, you will finally succeed. If you should still struggle after that time and trial, let me know.