# creating a bar that indicates the length of the line segment using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to plot some wind speed and direction data by ggplot2.
So I coded like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
  long = 1:4,
  lat = 2,
  wd_x = cos(1:4),
  wd_y = sin(1:4),
  ws = 1:4
)

data %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = long, y = lat,
                   xend = long + wd_x * ws / 5,
                   yend = lat + wd_y * ws / 5),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.15, "cm")))
```

which gives the following plot:

[image]

.

Now I want to indicate that one unit length of the arrow is equal to 5m/s of wind speed, or equally, one-fifth unit length of the arrow is equal to 1m/s of wind speed. How can I create a scale bar that indicates the wind speed(ws) here?

Comment: Do you want a *legend* where the segments correspond to the length?

Comment: Here is a very (!) similar dupoid question where the proposed solution is to add a fake legend via custom annotation (disclaimer: this is my answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69810305/adding-legend-for-velocity-plot-key-glyph-length-to-represent-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you intend to create a legend that shows arrows that represent the length/velocity/speed of your vectors from the main plot. [There is a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69810305/adding-legend-for-velocity-plot-key-glyph-length-to-represent-value), but the given answer (disclaimer: my answer) has not been upvoted nor accepted, thus I feel hesitant to close this question as a duplicate.

The suggested solution is to create a fake legend via annotation.

NB: your calculation of vector length looks wrong to me. (this also being the reason why the length of arrows in the legend in my plot is so much longer). It is difficult to guess your intended vector lengths from your provided data, but the formula to calculate length of the segment would be

> xend = x + speed * cos(direction[angle] * pi / 180)

> yend = y + speed * sin(direction[angle] * pi / 180)

whereby 0 degree is pointing right which is more common  convention, but may not always be.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
  long = 1:4,
  lat = 2,
  wd_x = cos(1:4),
  wd_y = sin(1:4),
  ws = 1:4
)

## I prefer to prepare data outside of ggplot calls
df <- data %>%
  mutate(xend = long + wd_x * ws / 5,
         yend = lat + wd_y * ws / 5)

## defining x or y coordinates for your annotation can be daunting.
## First get x and y range 
ylims <- range(c(df$lat, df$yend))
xlims <- range(c(df$long, df$xend))
df_leg <-
  data.frame(
    ws = c(1, 5),
    y = ylims[1] - c(ylims[1]/1.6, ylims[1]/1.3),
    x = xlims[1]
  ) %>%
  ## for the label x coord
  mutate(xend = x + ws)

## your plot, just slightly modified
ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = long, y = lat,
                   xend = xend, yend = yend),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.15, "cm"))) +
  geom_segment(
    data = df_leg,
    aes(
      x = x, y = y, xend = xend,
      yend = y
    ), 
    ## you need to experiment with the arrow head length, I'd pass a vector
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(3:4, "pt")), show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = df_leg, aes(x = xend, y = y, label = paste(ws, "m/s")),
    hjust = -.1
  ) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1, xlim = xlims, ylim = ylims, clip = "off") +
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        plot.margin = margin(r = 2.6, unit = "in"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Nice @tjebo. I agree that annotations are probably the way to go here. Won't the arrow length for the same windspeed vary with this method, though? Does a 1 m/s North arrow have the same length as a 1m/s East arrow with this aspect ratio? Or have you taken that into account already?

Comment: thanks @AllanCameron.  I think it should be taken into account already - the reason for which I added coord_fixed(ratio = 1)

Comment: Ah, I missed the unnamed first argument. I think that makes it the same as `coord_equal`?

Comment: @AllanCameron yeah I copied it from my other answer and I agree I should have named the argument for better clarity (done this now). I think I used it because coord_equal did not allow setting limits back then, but maybe this has changed now